# Am I able to use the Chrome version of the Mindstorm software on a Windows/Mac laptop?

Tags: ev3, software, mac

We currently teach Lego robots as part of our Technology curriculum, but we are 1-to-1 in a BYOD environment. So we have all different types of devices the students use including Chromebooks, Windows and MacOS.

Is there a way a Windows (or MacOS) user can use the Chrome app version of Mindstorm software?

I keep getting a message to go do "Lego Downloads" to when I try to open the app in a Chrome browser.

Answer (score 4):

LEGO Education has a new programming software called **EV3 Classroom** that will work on Windows, Mac and Chromebooks that can run Android apps. This is probably the best option for the devices listed but won't work on all Chromebooks. It is available from the [LEGO Education download page](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software#downloads).

The retired [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lego%C2%AE-mindstorms%C2%AE-educati/jhnhfnolmcleankdkhfklakpchnccipg) only works on Chromebooks.

[MakeCode](https://makecode.mindstorms.com/) could be an option too.